# Linking xml schema namespace to instance xml instance

Tags: xml, xquery, exist-db

I am new to xml and using existdb to create a basic database. I have a schema xml with targetNamespace defined and I am using that namespace as schemaLocation in instance xml. However, I don't understand when the instance document gets evaluated against schema. Even if I put invalid schema in instance document, all queries work. Am I missing something? How do we link schema and instance xmls and both with the xquery?

```
instance document:

    <entities xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://NamespaceTest.com/CommonTypes schema.xsd">
    ...
    </entities>

schema document(document name is schema.xsd)
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/CommonTypes">
...
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

Validation against a schema can be performed either by an XML parser or by a specialist schema validator, and in either case the schema location can be obtained either from the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute or from elsewhere. With one or two possible exceptions, most software that reads XML does not trigger validation merely because it sees an `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute. There are many schema validators and many different ways of enabling schema validation, but it usually won't happen unless you request it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out here: [eXist-db: Programmatically validate an XML document](http://www.exist-db.org/exist/apps/demo/examples/basic/validation.html)

Or here: [eXist-db: XML Validation](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/validation)

*"...Implicit validation.
Implicit validation is executed automatically when documents are inserted into the database.
To enable implicit validation, change eXist-db configuration by editing conf.xml. The following two items must be configured:
(1) Validation mode
   (2) Catalog Entity Resolver
..."*